# Create array dynamically for javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to show markers on google map. And it is working fine if I use static array for marker's lat and long.

But when I try to make dynamic using php array, then it is not working.

Here is the code.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var var_locations = <?=json_encode($locations)?>;

/****** Array which need to make Dynamic *********/
var locations=[
        ['Location <br>Name', 13.0104292, 77.64844689999995, 1],
        ['Location <br>Name', 28.6699553, 77.10752720000005, 1],
    ];
    function initialize() {
        console.log(locations);
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.5937, 78.9629),
            zoom: 3,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        };
        var map = new  google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapOptions);

        var  i;
        

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            
          var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: locations[i][0],
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map,
                title:locations[i][0]
            });  
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(mm, tt) {
        return function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(tt);
            infoWindow.open(map, mm);
        }
    })(marker, locations[i][0]));

        }
        

    }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);    

});
```

I want following array in above code to be dynamic

```
var locations=[
    ['Location <br>Name', 13.0104292, 77.64844689999995, 1],
    ['Location <br>Name', 28.6699553, 77.10752720000005, 1],
];
```

For that I am using following code to make it dynamic

```
var var_locations = <?=json_encode($locations)?>;
var locations=[
       var_locations.forEach(function(item) {
            [item.clinicName, item.latitude, item.longitude],
        });
    ];
```

But it is not working. To test whether loop is working, I tried to print in console value (`item.latitude`) in loop, And values are being printed, Means loop is working fine.

But if I use loop inside js array then it is not working. Nor giving error through which I can identify some problem.

How I can make that array dynamic?

> Update

```
[
{
    "clinicName": "Dummy clinic",
    "doctorName": "Any name",
    "phoneNumber": 234242342,
    "address": "test address, city",
    "latitude": "13.0104292",
    "email": "user@gmail.com",
    "longitude": "77.64844689999995"
},
{
    "clinicName": "Dummy clinic",
    "doctorName": "Any name",
    "phoneNumber": 234242342,
    "address": "test address, city",
    "latitude": "13.0104292",
    "email": "user@gmail.com",
    "longitude": "77.64844689999995"
},
]
```

This is json array, I am getting from api. And I converted that array in php array to make it use on my page.

Comment: You are creating a new array `[item.clinicName, item.latitude, item.longitude]` inside that forEach loop, but you are not _doing anything_ with it. And wrapping that forEach statement "into" `var locations=[...]`, also make little sense. Initialize `locations` as an empty array, then do the `var_locations.forEach` (not _wrapped_ into "array syntax", but on its own) - and then simply _push_ the new array items you are creating, into the `locations` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forEach does not return anything. Also you do not have any JSON in the client. It is already an object

You need a map  - unless you simply create the array as it is supposed to look like on the server

Here I also convert the lat/long to a float

```js
const locations = [
{
    "clinicName": "Dummy clinic",
    "doctorName": "Any name",
    "phoneNumber": 234242342,
    "address": "test address, city",
    "latitude": "13.0104292",
    "email": "user@gmail.com",
    "longitude": "77.64844689999995"
},
{
    "clinicName": "Dummy clinic",
    "doctorName": "Any name",
    "phoneNumber": 234242342,
    "address": "test address, city",
    "latitude": "13.0104292",
    "email": "user@gmail.com",
    "longitude": "77.64844689999995"
},
].map(item =>  ([item.clinicName, +item.latitude, +item.longitude]))
console.log(locations)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the JSON is an array of objects.

```js
const json = [{
  clinicName:"Location 1",
  latitude:13.0104292,
  longitude: 77.64844689999995
},{
  clinicName:"Location 2",
  latitude:13.0104292,
  longitude: 77.64844689999995
}];

const locations = json.map(location => ([location.clinicName, location.latitude,location.longitude ]));
console.log(locations);
```

Comment: There is no JSON here

Comment: The json var is what I assumed ```<?=json_encode($locations)?>```would output.

Comment: It outputs JSON but it is already an object when the const is assigned